# Showing AJAX Confrimation into a modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which basically inserts the form data into database. I am doing this by AJAX request. Now, So when the data is inserted the success info of "rentinsert.php" is shown in the form page which is showing "Your order has bee placed". What i want to do is to show it into a modal. So how to show the success message upon AJAX in a modal. Below is my code -

the html -

```
<form method="post"  id="rentalform" action="rentinsertdb.php">
     <div class="form-group space" >
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter full name" name="rentname">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group space" >
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choose your ride</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
           <div class="dropdown">
              <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="rentcar" >
              <option>Choose your ride</option>
              <option value="Toyota Alion 2008">Toyota Alion 2008</option>
              <option value="Toyota Alion 2008">Toyota Premio 2008</option>
              <option value="Toyota Alion 2008">Toyota Corolla 2006</option>
              <option value="Toyota Alion 2008">Toyota Noah 2010</option>
           </select>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <!-- <div class="form-group space" >
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="focusedinput" placeholder="Enter phone number">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
           <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
     </div> -->
     <div class="form-group space" >
        <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rentphone" placeholder="Enter phone number">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
           <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group space">
        <label for="txtarea1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pick up address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 tabular-border"><textarea  name="rentaddress" cols="50" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Full Address; For example: House#38, Road 7/a, Dhanmondi, Dhaka-1205, Bangladesh"></textarea></div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 space">
        <button class="btn-primary btn" style="background-color:#03a9f4; border-color:#03a9f4;" id="submitrent"> Confirm </button>
     </div>
     </form>
  </div>
  <span id="result"></span>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#submitrent").click( function() {
     $.post( $("#rentalform").attr("action"),
     $("#rentalform :input").serializeArray(),
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
     });
     // clearInput();
     });

     $("#rentalform").submit( function() {
        return false;
     });
// function clearInput() {
//     $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
//        $(this).val('');
//     });
// }
  </script>
```

rentinsert.php -

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

include_once "rentconnection.php";

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($_POST);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `rental`
(`name`,`car`,`phone`,`address`)
VALUES ('".$_POST['rentname']."','".$_POST['rentphone']."','".$_POST['rentcar']."','".$_POST['rentaddress']."');";

if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){

?> 

<body style= "background-color:#1D726A">

<h1>Your Order Has Been Placed! </h1>

</body>

<?php

    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `echo` your message when you successfully insert data into database

```
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "<body style= 'background-color:#1D726A'><h1>Your Order Has Been Placed! </h1></body>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Hi,edited my question. Actually i am successful in showing the "Your order has been placed" in thr forms page right now. What i want to do is to show it into a modal. So do i do in the php page which inserts the data into database? or in the form page?

Comment: What does model mean??

Comment: modal. Like bootstrap modal. 

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

I am not sure whether to put the modal in the form page or in the php page where the data is being inserted and success message is showing.

Comment: @hhs you need something like this `function(info){
 $('#myModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(".modal-body").html(info);
 });
});`

Comment: @hhs you need to put the modal HTML in form page.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Your Order Has Been Placed!'));
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Add modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="msg">Message here!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Show message in view

```
("#submitrent").click( function() {
        $.post( $("#rentalform").attr("action"),
        $("#rentalform :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info){
           var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(info);
           $("#msg").html(obj.message);
           $("#modal-content").modal('show');
        });
    // clearInput();
    });
```